# Is there a better way avoid rebuilding a Singularity image if the definition file hasn't changed?

Tags: singularity-container

I'm building Singularity images in a CI/CD pipeline. I'd like to avoid rebuilding the image if the definition file hasn't changed. So far, the best way that I can see to do this would be to check for changes using something like this:

```sh
if diff my_img.def <(singularity inspect -d my_img.sif) > /dev/null; then
    ... do something ...
fi
```

Is there a built-in or better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the CI software you're using, you can have certain jobs run only when specific files have changed. I use Gitlab CI, which has the [`only/except:changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#onlychangesexceptchanges) rule. There is probably something similar for most other CI platforms, but you'll have to check their docs.

Otherwise, your solution is probably the simplest.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I do use GitLab-CI for some of my CI and didn't realize that `only:changes` existed. Thanks for that! I'll have to continue doing what I'm doing in CI for other projects, but for those that run in GitLab-CI, I'll definitely make use of this.